# How to get the first element value of the splitted array

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

How to get the first element value of the splitted array

```
var supplierpofileselection = $("[id$='_SelectedTabIdsHiddenField']").val();
var arr = supplierpofileselection.split(';');
var arrfirst = arr.first();
alert (arrfirst);
```

List is random.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `index` to access the element of array.

*Change*

```
var arrfirst = arr.first();
```

*To*

```
var arrfirst = arr[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Split method returns an array of substrings. So use indexes 0,1,2... to access value.

```
var supplierpofileselection = $("[id$='_SelectedTabIdsHiddenField']").val();
var arr = supplierpofileselection.split(';');
var arrfirst = arr[0];
alert (arrfirst);
```